# Table Overflow columns are not showing in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

I have a table with around 20 columns width. When I tried to create as PDF through TCPDF plugin, around 8 to 10 columns only displaying and the remaining columns are not printed in the pdf. Anyone can have any suggestions please help me to fix this. See screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the page in portrait mode

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```